# can not connect zammad remotely, outside

Tags: ip, ubuntu-20.04, zammad

I have installed zammad on ubuntu 20.4,
I can open zammad with **localhost** address but can not connect to zammad from remote with server IP address

I have edited the file /etc/nginx/sites-available/zammad.conf

```
#
# this is the nginx config for zammad
#

upstream zammad-railsserver {
    server 127.0.0.1:3000;
}

upstream zammad-websocket {
    server 127.0.0.1:6042;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    # replace 'localhost' with your fqdn if you want to use zammad from remote
    #server_name localhost;
    server_name 10.20.60.200;

    # security - prevent information disclosure about server version
    #server_tokens off;

    root /opt/zammad/public;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/zammad.access.log;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/zammad.error.log;

    client_max_body_size 50M;
```

for **server_name** I have put my IP adress, and with this IP address can not connect to zammad, but with 127.0.0.1:3000 it is connecting

can anyone help on thi, please?

Answer (score 0):

Give in the URL `10.20.60.200:3000`. It is enough, when you just only give the IP adress without port into the URL.

Comment: I put FQDN in nginx file, after that it worked fine